# How to display the contents of snmpwalk() nicely using PHP?

Tags: php, networking, snmp

I'm currently using snmpget($host,$community,$oid,$timeout) to fetch every OID of my router.

Now, I want to display everything using snmpwalk() but I'm having a hard time to determine which is which. Could somebody help me to organize the contents of snmpwalk()?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try snmprealwalk
Also see documentation on php.net
http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmprealwalk.php